# Excel: How do I use one or another separate formulas in one cell, based on values in another?

Tags: excel

How do I use one or another separate formulas in one cell, based on values in another? Link to image below will show the issue.
Thanks
 Update to new Formula:
=IF(OR(E292="",F292=""),"",IF(F292<=E292,"On Time",IF(J292<>"","3rd Party","Late")))

[new screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJtvP.jpg)

[Screen shot if isse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGmto.jpg)

Comment: You should also put your current equation in the question so the volunteers here can simply copy/paste :)

Comment: Where possible don't supply only images of code/formulas/data as we cannot copy those for testing. You can use tools line [markdown table generators](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to input data formatted properly, and code/formula can be  edited via [edit] into the question, highlight the code/formula and press Ctrl + K

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slight change to your logic we can shorten the formula and add another nested if to test on the blanks.

```
=IF(OR(E3="",F3=""),"",IF(F3<=E3,"On Time",IF(K3<>"","3rd Party","Late")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @MutantDrone after the question is 15 minutes old you will be able to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Please do so as it will remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: I am getting a circular reference error. I will post a screenshot in a couple of minutes.

Comment: formula used: =IF(OR(E292="",F292=""),"",IF(F292<=E292,"On Time",IF(J292<>"","3rd Party","Late")))

Comment: `J292` should be `K292`